# Rails: specify foreign_key/parent_class at one place when using model namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I decided to move all user logic into separate folder `app/models/user/*`.
Let's say I have there file `main.rb`, which defines constant `User::Main`.

When I ran rspec test, I found that pretty much every association test fails.

Problem is that either Rails does not know that

```
belongs_to :user
```

means since there is not `User` constant anymore.

Either Rails attempts to find wrong foreign key:

```
User::Main.last.build_api_token
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'main_id' for ApiToken.
```

So there is a solution: I need to change every `belongs_to`like this:

```
belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User::Main'
```

(here at least I can use concerns)

and I need to specify every `foreign_key`

```
has_many :api_tokens, foreign_key: "user_id"
```

But making necessary to do this much of additional edits in many different files/lines confuses me.

For first issue I can use concerns module, but what about second one?

How can I set foreign key, by which Rails will work with association, once for all children.

```
module User
 class Main < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.accessible_by_key "user_id" #pseudocode to illustrate what I think of
 end
end
```

P.S. I found `add_foreign_key` [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key), but not sure if it is what I look for.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by splitting out logic into this, for example, User::Main class? This smells of the wrong approach to me -- perhaps you really want to be building other models (which can be non-ActiveRecord) to handle specific business logic or concerns? It seems like you're trying to split up a class that is represented in a single table (users) into multiple, and I'd advise against that battle. Check out http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ - some good ideas there for refactoring fat models.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz, thanks, I thought that if you want to put all (for example) registration/restoration account related models in folder /models/user/ you need to wrap every `/models/user/some_class.rb` `SomeClass` constant in `module User`. However, it is not required. Now I see that if I just want to group models by folders I don't need to wrap them in any additional modules

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, and what you are trying to accomplish is to modularize your User model, You can use the following approach:

1. Keep `user.rb` (the model) in the usual place, inside `app/models` folder.
2. Create a module inside `app/models/concerns`; for example `user_common.rb`.
3. Inside `user_common.rb` you can have something this:

   ```
   #app/models/concerns/user_common.rb

   module UserCommon

     extend ActiveSupport::Concern

     included do
       validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i }
     end

     def custom_method

     end
     ...
   end
   ```
4. In your User model, just call the module:

   ```
   #app/models/user.rb

   class User < ActiveRecord::Base

     include UserCommon

     ...
   end
   ```

I hope that helps.